# Magento1.9 : how to get all registered mails which is in active

Tags: magento-1.9

For Email validation am checking customer exists or not, I wrote code like this for updating email in my account page.

```
       $cus = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('email');
        foreach($cus  as $user){
        $custEmail[]=$user['email'];
        }

        if(in_array($customer->getEmail(),$custEmail)){
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('email already exists'));
        }else{
            $this->_getSession()->setCustomer($customer)->addSuccess($this->__('Not Exists.'));
        }
```

Here all emails are getting , I want only confirmation activation mails.Can anyone guide me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below code to get only confirmed customers data:**

```
$customerCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
$customerCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$customerCollection->addAttributeToFilter('confirmation', array('null' => true), 'left');


foreach($customerCollection  as $customer){
    $custEmail[]=$customer['email'];
}
```